# Searching for postal code map of Germany for R

Tags: r, maps, postal-code

I'm searching for a map of Germany which is divided into the different postal codes and could be coloured in R. Possible would be a map like this on wikipedia:

https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/cd/Karte_Paketzentren_Deutsche_Post_AG.png

Is there any package which is supporting this?

Comment: Search packages such as `maps` or `maptools` that can maybe provide you a map of Germany. Another way would be to search for a shapefile for your map to draw it with `ggplot2` and `rgdal` packages.

Comment: This blog article could also help: https://www.r-bloggers.com/case-study-mapping-german-zip-codes-in-r/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can download the Geojson (I advise this format) from https://public.opendatasoft.com/explore/dataset/georef-germany-postleitzahl/export/

You can then read the Geojson with the  `sf package`. You will find support for this on stackoverflow. Through the sf package you will have graphing possibilities with various other packages.
You can also download shapefiles for "Landkreis" and other administrative areas in Germany on this site.

Comment: new link: https://public.opendatasoft.com/explore/dataset/georef-germany-postleitzahl/export/

Comment: I've edited the answer to update the link.